# display: none not working in React component

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component creating 2000 markers for a Google map, and I'm going to be installing a script to make them visible/hidden based on conditions. In the interim, I'm simply testing and discovered that I cannot get display: none to work on the component whether input as an inline style or via a variable. Here's the current code (this component is being accessed in the return function of a parent component). The styling appears in the return  statement:

```
const CoordinatesFunction = (props) => {
  let RunCoordinates = _.times(2000, function() {
    let longitude = (Math.random() * (170 - -170) + -170).toFixed(7) * 1;
    let latitude = (Math.random() * (80 - -80) + -80).toFixed(7) * 1;
    let url = "";
    let nwRef = React.createRef();    
        if (latitude >=0 && latitude <= 90 && longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 0) {
            url="https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png";
            {props.store.dispatch(IncreaseNorthwest());}          

          } else if ( latitude <=0 && latitude >= -90 && longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 0 ) {
            url="https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png";
            {props.store.dispatch(IncreaseSouthwest());}

          } else if ( latitude >=0 && latitude <= 90 && longitude >= 0 && longitude <= 180 ) {
            url="https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png";
            {props.store.dispatch(IncreaseNortheast());}

          } else if ( latitude <=0 && latitude >= -90 && longitude >= 0 && longitude <= 180 ) {
            url="https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png";
            {props.store.dispatch(IncreaseSoutheast());}
          }
    return <div key={Math.random()} ref={nwRef} style={{ display: 'none' }}>
      <Marker
          position={{lat: latitude, lng: longitude}}
          icon={{ url: url,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25), size: new google.maps.Size(22, 22) }}
      >
      </Marker>
    </div>
  })
  return(<div>{RunCoordinates}</div>)
}
```

Comment: your code seems to be ok, when you inspect the element in your browser you don't see the `style` attribute in the `div` ?

Comment: No, and the ref doesn't show either.

Comment: `ref` is only used by `react`, it will not be added to the dom

Comment: Ahhh ... well done. I should have known that! But still not seeing the styling in the dev tools.